# how to prevent html code reload on button click event in GWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gwt, jsni

I created a button in GWT and on button click event i tried to get the text of div in alert box. so i did the following

```
Button btnClick = new Button("Click Me");
getElement().setInnerHTML("<div id='dummy'>This is dummy Text</div>");
btnClick.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // handle the click event
        Window.alert(getImageStr());
    }
});
RootPanel.get("dummy").add(btnClick);
```

And this is the method declaration:

```
private native String getDummyText() /*-{
        return document.getElementById("dummy").innerText;
}-*/;
```

But when i try to run it. it throws an exception

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`

and when i saw in inspect element while stopping at break point in javascript, i was shocked to see many scripts in body tag and no HTML at that moment and when i release that break point, it created HTML again. Please anyone help me out. i am badly stuck in that. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `document` with `$doc` in JSNI code:

> When accessing the browser's window and document objects from JSNI,
>   you must reference them as $wnd and $doc, respectively. Your compiled
>   script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically
>   initialized to correctly refer to the host page's window and document.

Comment: this is exactly what i was doing wrong. Thanks a lot. you solved my problem in which i was stuck for a whole day.